# What is Smurfing in online games?

Tags: terminology

What does Smurfing mean when applied to online games?

Comment: those youngsters... back when I was young, smurfing was delivering some Gbyte to someone's 33.6 Kbit modem with a flood of ICMP Echo Reply, by spoofing the source address of an ICMP Echo Request and sending it to an unprotected broadcast address.... I don't know where we are going with this youth.

Comment: @Stefano I was wondering this also and was thinking exactly the same, I edited the question to match the answers.

Comment: Adding the "in Online Games" part to the question is rather redundant considering the site this question was posted to. Taking out the smurfette reference was a low blow as well. Having a sense of humor is impossible on these troll driven sites.

Comment: We do play games besides online games, so it's not redundant because of the site.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/where-does-the-term-smurfing-come-from

Comment: @StefanoBorini, Wasn't "smurfing" a financial term before that era?

Comment: just as a side node: some smurf want lose all games while they using unwanted names.. (but sometimes that doesn't work either: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLrMxRB-4bo )

Answer (score 29):

In the context of Starcraft (and it is different in other games), smurfing referred to utilizing an account with a lower ranking (usually ICCUP) than is accurate for you as a player, to beat up on lesser players.

Since Starcraft 2 has a built in ELO style system, this would mean buying a new account (or destroying your own ranking) and losing all your matches to be placed in a league below your skill level (or using one that is already in such a position).

Since ELO style ranking systems require a sample size of multiple games to make accurate prediction of the skill level, players can trick the system into believing they possess a lower skill level.

Smurfing is not unique to ELO style rankings either.  Many tournaments are held for lower skilled players and by misrepresening themselves, highly skilled players can enter these tournaments.  This often times constitutes fraud or cheating, but may be by design.  For example, the Team Liquid Attack pits a professional player against a series of lesser players.  Often times they will intentionally mix in another professional player and present him as a lesser player for comedic value.  This is by design (and fun to watch).

Usually, however, smurfing is tantamount to taking candy from a baby.

Comment: Just as a side note, I think Blizzard does have some measures in place to thwart most smurfing attempts. My friend intentionally lost all his placement matches, putting him in Bronze league, but then game placed him in Platinum after only a few wins. I'd be curious to know how they were able to detect this so quickly.

Comment: @Carl the match maker is actually fairly aggressive in its estimations so it doesn't take many wins before it starts to match you well beyond your current rank.  However, there is no fool proof method for detecting someone who wins 1 in 5 games intentionally.

Comment: @Kyralessa unlikely, they probably do an exponential increase off of some constant which is based on the number of games you've played.

Comment: You started "smurfing"?

Comment: @Doug I started this guy's question because I mentioned smurfing in a different question he asked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure smurf accts are also used to test new strategies in StarCraft. Like a new "maneuver" for instance that one would not want to test on their actual acct.

Comment: In the competitive Team Fortress 2 community, this is called "sandbagging"

Comment: @tzenes, What does the last paragraph mean?

Answer (score 12):

The term smurfing certainly predates Starcraft 1.  I think it was invented by a guy named Shlonglor during the Kali days of Warcraft 2, sometime in 1996.

Shlonglor was well-known as a world-class player, but he'd occasionally go incognito with other high level players and beat up on average players.

On at least one occasion (maybe the first) they'd use smurf names (PapaSmurf, etc) and I think that's where the term came from.

Here's a link to web page (circa 1996) dicussing it:

http://nathandemick.com/warcraft2-stories/story13.shtml

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papa_Smurf

Answer (score 6):

From my understanding (from various games such as Warcraft III and Diablo 2), Smurfing refers to a player creating a new account or character and using that for various reasons, instead of just using their mainstream account.

Reason could be to take a break from high-level game play (pub-stomp), or if a gamer is popular, use a separate account (smurf) to avoid private messages from fans. Another common reason is if you just feel like avoiding your e-friends (if you are in a bad mood/unfriendly mood for instance).

A specific example is in Wc3, If someone wants to try a new strategy, they will create a smurf account, test it in games until they get it down, then use it on their main account without the losses being on their record (from the testing). This isn't always an accepted method and is most times frowned upon.

Comment: i used to go on a smurf acct with a buddy in WC3 and just do crazy strategies in arranged team matches. they rarely worked, but it was really fun and often got a good "WTF" or laugh out of the opposing team. and when they did work, well, that was fun too

Comment: I've done the same thing, Ridiculous cheese strategies or other all-in type jokester moves..pretty awesome :D

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurfing_%28online_gaming%29) entry about it. And the even more fun (but NSFW) [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SMURFING) definition. It appears it's generally a term for griefing or masking ones "appearance" to remain anonymous. Perhaps synonymous with "hustling".

Comment: Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hustling

Answer (score 1):

Smurfing is when a high level player makes a new account so they can fight less skilled players and get an advantage. This works because they have a better understanding of tactics and game mechanics.

Comment: While this is a nice short summary of the other answers, it really doesn't add anything that hasn't been said.

Comment: No one has said that it involves making a new account.

Comment: Look at Josh k's answer ;)